# How to push supervisor so I can publish papers?

Tags: publications, advisor, postdocs

I have been a while in my postdoc. I need to publish papers so that I can move ahead. I specifically need papers from this job because papers from my current job shape my future positions. My supervisor is not in a hurry to publish papers with me because he has enough papers coming out with other authors. For example, in the early days we worked on a paper and my supervisor held it to review for several months and did not make it a priority. Later, big changes were made, so it is taking longer.

Everything else is perfect as a supervisor except the paper publishing part. If my supervisor was pushing papers little bit harder, I could have 2-3 papers so far. **How should I push my supervisor to publish those papers?** Is this common among other postdocs as well?

Comment: I think you need to add some details to make this answerable. Why do you need you supervisor to publish?

Comment: Is the supervisor a co-author or is your work independent? Are you willing/able to be corresponding author?

Comment: Afaik if your paper gets published, that is a result also for the supervisor; at least if its content is something for which the SV can be pride. So, poke his ego and try to understand him in this frame.

Comment: @Buffy supervisor is a co-author.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to write a draft, present it to him and follow up. That is how you push. You say your PI is supportive. If that is true then he won't mind you taking the initiative and even having a conversation about how important you think it is to publish your work.

Comment: Indeed, the purpose of doing a postdoc is to show you are an independent researcher. The OP should be driving the interaction, not continuing to act like a new PhD student.

Comment: Still needs to do work towards the project goals. There are very limited time to do things independently while being in a project. @Jon.

Comment: @Dr.Baje - one can be in charge of things on a project, demonstrating independence. After 40 years as a student, postdoc, PI, and manager I’ve shepherded several dozen postdocs to being good PIs.

Comment: @Dr. Bake As a postdoc you should be expected to lead projects not just "be in a project". That leadership includes publishing and presenting your work. If you really want to publish you have to own that responsibility.